# NodeJS: Import all local variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a project on TypeScript and I need to run compiled JS file on NodeJS. The problem is I can't change TypeScript file. The problem is TypeScript compiler makes `var mymodule` and attaches all variables and functions to this `var`. And I don't know how to import this module to NodeJS. Can I import all variables (including local) in NodeJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Do things right

TypeScript project should use CommonJS module system.

### Add exports manually

If you can not change module system, you can add this at the end of your `.ts` file:

```
declare var module: { exports };
if (typeof module === "object" && module.exports)
    module.exports = mymodule;
```

### Export several submodules

You can write `this.mymodule1 = ...` instead of `var mymodule1 = ...`. This mode works in both Node.js and browser.

### Use "eval"

> I can't change TypeScript file

If you can not change `.ts` file at all, use `eval` in dependent `.js`:

```
var fs = require("fs");
eval(fs.readFileSync("myTSModule.js", "utf8"));

mymodule.myCoolMethod("hello");
```

### Use "runInContext"

Also you can isolate running context of ambient module by [`runInContext`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_script_runincontext_contextifiedsandbox_options):

```
var context = vm.createContext();
vm.runInContext(code, context);
var mymodule = context.mymodule;
```